# Document Similarity - Multiple documents ended with same similarity score

Tags: nlp

I have been working in a business problem where i need to find a similarity of new document with existing one.
I have used various approach as below

1.Bag of words + Cosine similarity

2.TFIDF + Cosine similarity

3.Word2Vec + Cosine similarity

None of them worked as expected.
But finally i found an approach which works better its
**Word2vec + Soft cosine** similarity

But the new challenge is i ended up with **multiple documents with same similarity score**.
Most of them are relevant but few of them even though having some semantically similar words they are different

Please suggest how to over come this issue

Comment: Could you please share a sample of about 10 sentences. If this sample has some sentences with acceptable similarity score as well as unacceptable ones, then one could investigate the problem better.

Comment: You can try [sentence-transformers](https://pypi.org/project/sentence-transformers/) embedding + cosine similarity as an alternative.

Comment: @SidharthMacherla Due to security policy i couldnot share that info but i try to mimic the scenario...I am having n number of historical docs with different tags or calsses (login issue, error message etc) i just want to find similarity of new document with existing. Now assume i am getting a doc like "Previously i was unable to connect which is resolved but now i am getting error message" due to the key words "unable to connect" and " error message" it gives same similarity score for both class documents eventhough its an error message realted documemt..I hope i have did my best in mimicing.

Comment: @arpitrathi thanks for the suggestion will try this

Answer (score 1):

If the objective is to identify semantic similarity, the following code sourced from [here](https://nlpforhackers.io/wordnet-sentence-similarity/) helps.

```py
#invoke libraries
from nltk import pos_tag, word_tokenize
from nltk.corpus import wordnet as wn

#Build functions 
def ptb_to_wn(tag):    
    if tag.startswith('N'):
        return 'n' 
    if tag.startswith('V'):
        return 'v' 
    if tag.startswith('J'):
        return 'a' 
    if tag.startswith('R'):
        return 'r' 
    return None


def tagged_to_synset(word, tag):
    wn_tag = ptb_to_wn(tag)
    if wn_tag is None:
        return None 
    try:
        return wn.synsets(word, wn_tag)[0]
    except:
        return None


def sentence_similarity(s1, s2):    
    s1 = pos_tag(word_tokenize(s1))
    s2 = pos_tag(word_tokenize(s2)) 

    synsets1 = [tagged_to_synset(*tagged_word) for tagged_word in s1]
    synsets2 = [tagged_to_synset(*tagged_word) for tagged_word in s2]

    #suppress "none"
    synsets1 = [ss for ss in synsets1 if ss]
    synsets2 = [ss for ss in synsets2 if ss]

    score, count = 0.0, 0

    for synset in synsets1:
        best_score = max([synset.path_similarity(ss) for ss in synsets2])
        if best_score is not None:
            score += best_score
            count += 1

    # Average the values
    score /= count
    return score

#Build function to compute the symmetric sentence similarity
def symSentSim(s1, s2):
    sss_score = (sentence_similarity(s1, s2) + sentence_similarity(s2,s1)) / 2
    return (sss_score)

#Example
s1 = 'We rented a vehicle to drive to Goa'
s2 = 'The car broke down on our jouney'            

s1tos2 = symSentSim(s1, s2)

print(s1tos2)
#0.155753968254
```