# Cosine Similarity with word2vec not giving good documemt similarity

Tags: nlp

Why cosine similarity with word embedding is not providing good output...Its giving similarity values of new document with most of the historical documents as high..eventhough both documents are not similar

Answer (score 0):

the cosine similarity gives how similar two vectors are based on the angle between them.

How do you construct the embedding of a document ? as word2vec will only give you the embedding of words?

Most people use tf-idf as a metric to rank documents.

Comment: I created word2vec for words in document and cosine similarity between documents to find similarity

Comment: An [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61258035/document-similarity-multiple-documents-ended-with-same-similarity-score/61300092#61300092) to another similar question could help. Please check.